# Mysql multiple condition statement

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble with my mysql query

```
SELECT 
    li.town,li.county,li.postCode,


IF(ca.qCode = '123456', ca.qCode_ans, 0) AS '123456',
IF(ca.qCode = '254668', ca.qCode_ans, 0) AS '254668',
IF(ca.qCode = '11234456', ca.qCode_ans, 0) AS '11234456'

FROM lead_info AS li 
LEFT JOIN call_info AS ci ON ci.leadID = li.leadID
LEFT JOIN cust_ans AS ca ON ca.callRecording = ci.callRecording
```

+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+------------
town|country|postcode|123456|254668|11234456 
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+-----------
Malan |Malasia |9999999|      Yes            |   0           | 0 
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+-----------
Malan |Malasia |9999999|                    |  No           | 0 
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+-----------
Malan |Malasia |9999999|                    |                  | Maybe 
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+-----------

What I need is

+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+------------
town|country|postcode|123456|254668|11234456 
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+-----------
Malan |Malasia |9999999|      Yes            |   No          | Maybe
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+-----------

Really need your help. THank you in advance.

Comment: I don't agree with the down votes here. The question shows code, current results, expected results, and an effort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `MAX` aggregate:

```
SELECT li.town, li.county, li.postCode,
  MAX(IF(ca.qCode = '123456', ca.qCode_ans, 0)) AS `123456`,
  MAX(IF(ca.qCode = '254668', ca.qCode_ans, 0)) AS `254668`,
  MAX(IF(ca.qCode = '11234456', ca.qCode_ans, 0)) AS `11234456`
FROM lead_info AS li 
LEFT JOIN call_info AS ci ON ci.leadID = li.leadID
LEFT JOIN cust_ans AS ca ON ca.callRecording = ci.callRecording
GROUP BY li.town, li.county, li.postCode
```